# Which file caused a header to be included?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header-files, watchos-2

I just upgraded our project to `watchOS 2` and i cannot build any more because apparently `MGLMapView.h` is now somehow included in the project. This is a header from `MapBox-gl` and it's not supposed to be used in the `watchOS` project at all.

I'm pretty sure some header included in the `watchOS` project includes another header file which in turn includes `MGLMapView.h`.

The problem is that i cannot figure out which file is causing this. Is there anything like a "show header include chain" feature?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks
Maciej

Comment: Show the complete error text generated by the compiler.

Comment: Ok forget it, turns out its enough to press the little arrow next to the error message and the "header include chain" shows up -.-

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself. Just keep pressing the arrows next to the error and the include chain will unfold.